# VMware Fusion の仮想NICを tcpdump したい

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion, network

OSX にて、VMware Fusion のホスト側の仮想NIC（vmnet1 や vmnet8）を tcpdump でキャプチャしたいのですが、以下のようなエラーが発生してキャプチャできません。

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i vmnet8
tcpdump: vmnet8: No such device exists
(BIOCSETIF failed: Device not configured)
```

なお、tcpdump に -i オプションを与えずに起動すると全てのNICのパケットがキャプチャでき、vmnet1 や vmnet8 のパケットも取得できます。

VMware Fusion の仮想NICは、単独でキャプチャすることはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のオプションで tcpdump を起動すると、vmnet8 を単独でキャプチャすることができます。

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i pktap,vmnet8
```

pktap とは、OSX（Darwin）独自の疑似インタフェースのことで、これを用いることで VMware Fusion の仮想NICを単独でキャプチャすることができるようになります。

pktap について詳しく書かれたブログ記事がありますのでURLを併記しておきます。

http://dsas.blog.klab.org/archives/52132993.html